# empty pointers to objects when compiling in opt but not in debug

Tags: c++, debugging, compilation

I am writing a C++ code and compiling it with gcc 4.7.1. I am writing a code using expression templates to assemble matrices and vectors, whose type is `MatrixEpetra` or `VectorEpetra` from `Trilinos`.

My problem is the following: the code should assemble a vector (for a finite element problem) using the expression I define and put the values inside the vector I give him. The vector is given to the assembling method using a `boost::shared_ptr`. The code works perfectly fine when I compile it in debug mode but the vector is not filled at all when I compile using the opt mode. What could be the problem?

I understand I am not posting pieces of code but it's just because I do not know which level of detail I should use here...I mean that the lines I would post are a lot and it's maybe inappropriate.

Comment: You need to post code.  Most likely you're doing something which is causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Since we're not mind readers...you'll need to show some code.  Show us the minimal amount of code necessary to clearly demonstrate the problem.  Ideally, it will be something that we can cut-and-paste-and-compile, but that's not always possible.

Comment: You need to post some code - maybe the code that populates the vector at least.  Of course, posting compilable code can help more!

Comment: Most likely you forget to initialize something and this is done in debug mode or you have code with necessary side-effects in an `assert` that is not run in debug mode.

Comment: A small example that reproduces the bug, and should ideally be compilable albeit it can be a function without a main and you don't need to bother to put in the necessarily #includes.

Comment: How was this question upvoted twice ?!

Answer (score 2):

Without more code to go on, my psychic debugging skills tell me that you didn't `resize` or `push_back` to increase the size of the vector but just used `operator[]` to add items to reserved memory.

Answer (score 0):

the code is the following:

```
      integrate( integrationOverSelectedVolumes( this->M_FESpace->mesh(), this->M_markerFunctorPtr ) ,
                 this->M_FESpace->qr(),
                 this->M_ETFESpace,
                 value(bulk / 2.0) * ( pow( J ,2.0) - J + log(J)) * dot(  F_T, grad(phi_i) )
                ) >> M_stiff;
```

where M_stiff is a boost::shared pointer to a VectorEpetra and the fourth line is the expression I need to evaluate and integrate. The first parameter to the function integrate (which is a constructor of a class called IntegrateVectorVolumeID) explains where the expression has to be integrated. Please note that I have substituted that integrationOverSelectedVolumes() with another type policy of integration (which I not it works) and I get the same behavior so the problem is not given buy that one. M_stiff is the pointer I was talking about. I do not think (but I am probably wrong) that I have forgotten an initialization since, in the setup method of the class I reset all the pointers to objects of the type the point to. As soon as I'll figure out an example (which is not easy for me since I am new to expression template and I still have a lot of doubts) I'll post it.

thanks,
pol